# How to search nested objects on Elasticsearch using elasticsearch.js and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

I want to search fields on a nested document on my elasticsearch db. I use the following command to search fields on a nested object (getting 10 inner hits):

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/jira-dev/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
"_source" : false,
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "issues",
        "query" : {
          "bool": {
            "should": [                   
              {
                "wildcard":{
                  "issues.fields.description":"*migrate*"
                } 
              },
              {
                "wildcard":{
                  "issues.fields.comment.comments.body":"*autodeploy*"
                } 
              }
            ]
          }               
        },
        "inner_hits" : {"size": 5000}
        }
    }   
}'
```

But when I try to call it using elasticsearch.js in this way, it does not get any result:

```
client.search({
    index: 'jira-dev/',
    type: 'jira',
    body: {
        query: {
            nested : {
                path : "issues",
                query : {
                    bool: {
                        should: [                   
                        {
                            wildcard:{
                                "issues.fields.description":"*migrate*"
                            } 
                        },
                        {
                            wildcard:{
                                "issues.fields.comment.comments.body":"*autodeploy*"
                            } 
                        }
                        ]
                    }               
                },
                inner_hits : {size: 5000}
            }
          }
      }
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.totals;
    console.log('works');
}, function (err) {
    console.log('epic fail');
    console.trace(err.message);
});
```

I suppose that the syntaxis that I am using is incorrect, but I have not found any example of nested queries using elasticsearch.js.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

As requested, following is the configuration of a document:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/jira-dev/' -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "jira" : {
            "properties" : {
                "expand" : {"type" : "string"},
                "startAt" : {"type" : "integer"},
                "maxResults" : {"type" : "integer"},
                "total" : {"type" : "integer"},
                "issues" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "include_in_parent" : false,
                    "properties" : {
                        "created" : {"type" : "date", "format" : "date_hour_minute_second_fraction"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 5,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }
}'
```

and an example:

```
{

    "_index": "jira-dev",
    "_type": "jira",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "expand": "schema,names",
        "startAt": 0,
        "maxResults": 1000,
        "total": 604,
        "issues": [
            {

                "key": "STACK-1",
                "fields": {
                    "summary": "A nice summary",
                    "created": "2016-06-28T09:45:32.000+0000",
                    "description": null,                    
                    "comment": {
                        "startAt": 0,
                        "maxResults": 1,
                        "total": 1,
                        "comments": [ 
                            {
                                "self": url",
                                "id": "30293",
                                "author": {
                                    "name": "stack_overflow",
                                    "key": "stack_overflow"
                                },
                                "body": "Following epic has been created: url",
                                "updateAuthor": {
                                    "name": "stack_overflow",
                                    "key": "stack_overflow",
                                    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
                                },
                                "created": "2016-03-04T10:09:11.000+0000",
                                "updated": "2016-03-04T10:09:11.000+0000"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how the structure of your documents look?

Comment: For sure, I have added an example and the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to skip this issue I has used a middleware server between angular and elastic. This server is a python server and is easy to do GET/POST on elasticsearch via curl.

Moreover, I tried to use curl directly from Angular (html GET), but due to convention, an html server can ignore data on a GET petition. Therefore, via curl from Angular it was impossible to do petitions on elastic.